# SQL query - find row which exceeds cumulative proportion

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-frequency

Say I have a table of data that looks like:

```
ItemNo    |    ItemCount   |    Proportion
------------------------------------------
1              3                0.15 
2              2                0.10
3              3                0.15
4              0                0.00
5              2                0.10
6              1                0.05
7              5                0.25
8              4                0.20
```

In other words, there are a total of 20 items, and the cumulative proportion of each `ItemNo` sums to 100%. The ordering of the table rows is important here.

Is it possible to perform a SQL query ***without loops or cursors*** to return the **first** `ItemNo` which exceeds a cumulative proportion?

In other words if the 'proportion' I wanted to check was 35%, the first row which exceeds that is `ItemNo 3`, because 0.15 + 0.10 + 0.15 = 0.40

Similarly, if I wanted to find the first row which exceeded 75%, that would be `ItemNo 7`, as the sum of all `Proportion` up until that row is less than 0.75.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select top 1
  t1.ItemNo
from
  MyTable t1
where
  ((select sum(t2.Proportion) from MyTable t2 where t2.ItemNo <= t1.ItemNo) >= 0.35)
order by
  t1.ItemNo
```

Answer (score 3):

A classic for a window function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (
    SELECT ItemNo
          ,ItemCount
          ,sum(Proportion) OVER (ORDER BY ItemNo) AS running_sum
    FROM   tbl) y
WHERE  running_sum > 0.35
LIMIT  1;
```

Works in **PostgreSQL**, among others.

<strike>Or, in **tSQL** notation (which you seem to use):

SELECT TOP 1 *

FROM   (

    SELECT ItemNo

          ,ItemCount

          ,sum(Proportion) OVER (ORDER BY ItemNo) AS running_sum

    FROM   tbl) y

WHERE  running_sum > 0.35;</strike>

Doesn't work in tSQL as commented below.

Comment: Is there a subtle difference in the syntax for use in Sql Server? When using your second example, I get `Incorrect syntax near 'order'.`

Comment: I may be mistaken but I don't think the OVER clause can be used to generate running totals in SQL Server, only rankings or a sum over a partition. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver/861073#861073 This is why I chose a subquery instead.

Comment: @njreed.myopenid.com: Ah, looks like you are right, doesn't work with tSQL. Good link. I crossed out the tSQL version. Please remember to disclose your RDBMS in your nest question. :)

Comment: @Erwin Thanks for clarification. Not specifying an RDBMS was a deliberate choice in order to get a generic SQL solution without the need to rely on vendor-specific functionality.